# how does actually the EJB work

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I am just new landing into EJB and wildfly world and start with a [basic example](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-as-7/jboss-as-7-remote-ejb-client-tutorial) that contains remote interface and remote implementation running in the server side (EJB Container) and an EJB client is trying to call these functionalities in the server side.

However what make me confused is the way that EJB works. In oder to run the program, we have to export the jar file of the EJB Container running in the server side which includes here some remote interface and the implementation, and then import this jar file to the client program so that this client can use the interface or methods in the implementation. So my question is if we use directly these jar files for our client's implementation then why we still need this EJB Container running in the server side? because for example if I change the interface or the implementation in the server side, then I still have to rechange my jar file in the client side so that I can continue using this implementation. Am I right? Sorry I am a little bit confused about this problem.

Comment: I would not start with remote EJBs - they are rarely used these days

Comment: See the below link: It may help: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+server+instance------------   https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project     -------------               https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

Comment: You need a Jar because you are not invoking the EJB directly, but the app server build instead a proxy for you to be used. You distribute your jar, which contains `@Local` or `@Remote` interfaces only, to clients. This is a crucial point, the app server gives you a proxy, and it is managing the lifecycles, scalability, transaction and all the rest.... Obviously if you change the method signature, you have to redistribute your jar.